# xml to empty datetime list

Tags: c#, xml, list, datetime

helllo guys i need help with implementing xml in c# datetime

this is c# function i try to get my dates to list and it throws that strign is not valid datetime

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Brivdienas.xml");
            List<DateTime> Holidays = new List<DateTime>();
            var a = from Brivdiena in doc.Descendants("Brivdiena") select (Brivdiena);
            foreach (var i in a)
                Holidays.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(i.Element("BrivDat").Value, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

here is xml where i try to get BrivDat column in my c# list

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Brivdienas>
  <Brivdiena>
    <BrivDat>1/1/2014</BrivDat>
    <BrivNos>Jaungada diena</BrivNos>
  </Brivdiena>
  <Brivdiena>
    <BrivDat>18/4/2014</BrivDat>
    <BrivNos>Lielā piektdiena</BrivNos>
  </Brivdiena>
  <Brivdiena>
    <BrivDat>20/4/2014</BrivDat>
    <BrivNos>Pirmās Lieldienas</BrivNos>
  </Brivdiena>
  <Brivdiena>
    <BrivDat>21/4/2014</BrivDat>
    <BrivNos>Otrās Lieldienas</BrivNos>
  </Brivdiena>
  <Brivdiena>
    <BrivDat>1/5/2014</BrivDat>
    <BrivNos>Darba svētki</BrivNos>
  </Brivdiena>
  <Brivdiena>
    <BrivDat>4/5/2014</BrivDat>
    <BrivNos>Latvijas Republikas Neatkarības deklarācijas pasludināšanas diena</BrivNos>
  </Brivdiena>
  <Brivdiena>
    <BrivDat>23/6/2014</BrivDat>
    <BrivNos>Līgo diena</BrivNos>
  </Brivdiena>
  <Brivdiena>
    <BrivDat>24/6/2014</BrivDat>
    <BrivNos>Jāņu diena</BrivNos>
  </Brivdiena>
  <Brivdiena>
    <BrivDat>18/11/2014</BrivDat>
    <BrivNos>Latvijas Republikas proklamēšanas diena</BrivNos>
  </Brivdiena>
  <Brivdiena>
    <BrivDat>24/12/2014</BrivDat>
    <BrivNos>Ziemassvētku vakars</BrivNos>
  </Brivdiena>
  <Brivdiena>
    <BrivDat>25/12/2014</BrivDat>
    <BrivNos>Pirmie Ziemassvētki</BrivNos>
  </Brivdiena>
  <Brivdiena>
    <BrivDat>26/12/2014</BrivDat>
    <BrivNos>Otrie Ziemassvētki</BrivNos>
  </Brivdiena>
  <Brivdiena>
    <BrivDat>31/12/2014</BrivDat>
    <BrivNos>ZVecgada diena</BrivNos>
  </Brivdiena>
</Brivdienas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern string incorrect. Both `dd` and `MM` expect leading zero for values < 10, e.g. `01/01/2014`. Your document does not have leading zeros, and the same date is provided as `1/1/2014`.

Use `d/M/yyyy` as a pattern instead.

Comment: ok now i got rid of error of invalid datetime how can i for example see list data in richtextbox ? for example  richtextbox1.lines = somestringlist.toarray(); how i implement this for datetime ?